# T-shirt image hover (based on different colors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover

So ive seen some jquery hover effects, but none that can do the multiple choices hover.
Basically i have 5 t-shirt color choices, that when each one is hovered over, it should pop up where the current (green t-shirt) is located.

Heres link - http://musclefire.com/26.php

Note: there will also be other t-shirt styles on this page as well, so not sure if this will be too much code/complex for this to work properly.

p.s. - whoever nails it and gets perfect code, i'll send out a free tee to ya!

thanks much!

Comment: Free t-shirt? Woohoo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for:

> #### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/jiNxcw9nHQD5gV4vvwlj?p=preview

#### HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <img class="active" src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-green.png" />
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-red.png" />
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-blue.png" />
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-charcoal.png" />
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-yellow.png" />
</div>
<div id="thumbs">
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-green.png" />
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-red.png" />
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-blue.png" />
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-charcoal.png" />
    <img src="http://musclefire.com/gear/muskull-yellow.png" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#main {
    border: solid 1px #eee;
    text-align: center;
}
#thumbs {
    border: solid 1px #eee;
    text-align: center;
}
#main img {
    width: 300px;
    display: none;
}
#main img.active {
    display: inline-block;
}
#thumbs img {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $('#thumbs img').bind('hover', function(){
      var which = $(this).attr('src');
      $("#main img:visible").hide();
      $('#main img[src="' + which +'"]').stop().fadeIn(800);
   });
});
```

Comment: send me email if you want one of the shirts!
ryan@musclefire.com

Answer (score 0):

All I know you cannot do this with css. So you should use **javascript** or **jquery** for this. 
The only way to do this with CSS is if the element to affect is either a descendent or an adjacent sibling.

For example:

```
.parent:hover .child{}
.child{}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You can do what you wanted with jquery,

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/XUM8R/